# Soil Texture in SAGA, GRASS and R

Tags: qgis, r, grass-gis, saga

I am trying to get a map with the type of soil depending of their texture. I have tried three options:

In SAGA.
By using the tool "soil texture classification" where by using three raster with the % of sand, silt and clay it was supposed that I was going to get a map with results between 1 - 12 (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/2.2.1/grid_analysis_14.html), but what I get it is a map with data between 254 and 255. Nothing to do with the expected result.

In R.
There is a package named "soiltexture", but when I try to install it I am giving this message: "ERROR: dependency ‘sp’ is not available for package ‘soiltexture’". I do not know how to fix this issue.

In GRASS.
It seems that there is a tool named "r.soils.texture", but I do not have this tool in my grass (QGIS 2.18.15).

So, I do not see more options to be able to get a map of soils by using any of these software.

Has anyone had any of these problems before?

Comment: The R problem shouldn't happen. How are you trying to install `soiltexture`? What version of R are you on? You might want to start a new question on here titled "Problem installing soiltexture R package" with full details.

Comment: I am using RStudio v1.1.383 in Anaconda in Linux.  First, I try to instal the package by using install.packages("soiltexture"), it is there when I am given the message: ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sp’.  I tried to install the package "sp" and then I get: ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘sp’, so I got lost...  many thanks for your answer.

Comment: Do you have installed `sp`?  Try to install this package first

Comment: Well, I have solved the problem of the sp package by installing it by using the command window and with conda instal r-sp.  I am working with Anaconda and when I tried to install it in R I got a problem.  Now, it seems that it works.... let's see.  Many thanks for help.

Comment: As per the [Tour] please try to always ask one specific question (about one specific GIS product) per question.  You can always ask about any others separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I recommend you to install correctly `soiltexture` and work in R. You should install it as:

```
install.packages('soiltexture',dependencies = T)
# or
install.packages('sp'); install.packages('soiltexture',dependencies = T)
```

After this, here you have a basic example:

---

Dummy data:

```
library(raster)
library(soiltexture)

r <- raster()
clay <- setValues(r,values = rnorm(n = ncell(r),mean = 30,sd = 1))
silt <- setValues(r,values = rnorm(n = ncell(r),mean = 30,sd = 1))
sand <- setValues(r,values = rnorm(n = ncell(r),mean = 40,sd = 1))

st <- stack(clay,silt,sand)

st_sum <- calc(st, fun = sum)

# data normalization

normSt <- list()

for (i in seq(3)) {
  normSt[[i]] <- st[[i]]/(st_sum/100)
}

normSt <- stack(normSt)

rasterVis::levelplot(normSt)
```

[image]

Convert rasters to `data.frame`, calculate soil data and add it back to a raster layer:

```
df <- as.data.frame(normSt)

names(df) <- c('CLAY','SILT','SAND')

df_classes <- TT.points.in.classes(tri.data = df, class.sys   = "USDA.TT", PiC.type = 't')

df_classes <- as.factor(df_classes)

r[] <- df_classes

rasterVis::levelplot(r)
```

[image]